# Speed up SqlBulkCopy .NETCore

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

I am really clueless here.

I import ~2 million rows into my Azure SQL database. I create a temp table where I put my values, when I use merge technique to insert only rows that do not have duplicates. My code and scripts are shown below.

```js
public async Task BulkImportWithoutDuplicates(DataTable reader)
{
    var tableName = "##tempImport";
 
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlCOnn.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", sqlCOnn))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlCOnn.Open();

                // Creating temp table on database
                command.CommandText = Scripts.GetTempTableScript();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Bulk insert into temp table
                using (SqlBulkCopy b = new SqlBulkCopy(conString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
                {
                    b.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    b.BatchSize = reader.Rows.Count;
                    b.DestinationTableName = tableName;
//dataTable 

                    await b.WriteToServerAsync(reader);

                    b.Close();
                 }

                 // Updating destination table, and dropping temp table
                 command.CommandText = Scripts.GetMergeScript();
                 var rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 // Handle exception properly
             }
             finally
             {
                 connection.Close();
             }
        }
    }
}

public static string GetTempTableScript()
{
    return $@" 
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##tempImport', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
            DROP TABLE ##tempImport;
            END
    
              CREATE TABLE ##tempImport ( ... all the columns);";
}
        
public static string GetMergeScript()
{
    return $@"MERGE INTO dbo.Data AS target
              USING ##tempImport AS source
                ON (source.TransactionId = target.TransactionId AND source.UserId = target.UserId)
               
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (Start, Spend, UserId, Product, Shop, ClientId, UploadDataId, UniqueId, TransactionId, q, cq, c2)
                        VALUES (source.Start, source.Spend, source.UserId, source.Product, source.Shop, 
                source.ClientId, source.UploadDataId, source.UniqueId, source.TransactionId, source.q, source.c1, source.c2);

               ";
        }
```

I really do not get why it takes ages until it finishes. I waited for 24 minutes  until it was added to temporary table alone.

I was reading this article and it seems that it shouldn't take long. https://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/sqlbulkcopy-to-sql-server-in-parallel.html?m=1

What I am doing wrong here? How can I improve the speed?

I tried using both `IDataReader` and `DataTable` but both of them do not work well for me...

Comment: I suspect it could be because you setting BatchSize to the number of rows you are copying. Have you tried not setting this and leaving it to the default value?

Comment: I tried 500, 5000,10000,100000

Comment: A LOT of people have a performance problem with SqlBulkCopy + Azure (because of some throttling maybe?), it will run super fast anywhere but on Azure. I recommend you to try on an external server (if you have one) to check the performance. Usually upgrading the tier makes it faster (obviously).

Comment: Try monitoring the DTU % used, if it’s at 100% you should pay more. 2 mil records should go fast if it’s scaled to P2